# Phpunit not connecing with mysql in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpunit

Symfony connect with database (and php container) but when I run phpunit return error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`. Where is mistake in my project ?

In my projekt docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 8989:3306
    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php7-fpm
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
        depends_on:
          - db
        links:
          - db:db
```

Answer (score 0):

The `environment` config of `db` service and `args` settings of `php` service should be started with `-` character.